# Getting "This site can’t be reached" when running angular 8 via docker compose

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I was able to run by npm start for my angular UI application. However, when I move API and UI into docker, I kept on hitting "This site can’t be reached". Can anyone help me to check the script where goes wrong?

```
**API Dockerfile:**

FROM node:10.16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is my api start script:

"dev": "nodemon index.js"

```
**UI Dockerfile**

FROM node:10.16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/ui

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular && npm install

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is my UI start script:

"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200", *** Someone recommended to add --host and --port, I did however still getting the same error.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app-api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: app-api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app/api
      - /usr/src/app/api/node_modules
  app-ui:
    build:
      context: ./ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    container_name: app-ui
    volumes:
      - ./ui:/usr/src/app/ui
      - /usr/src/app/ui/node_modules
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app-ui
      - app-api
```

I added nginx:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app-ui:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://app-api:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

When build and run docker-compose up no error.
[image]

[image]

I am using windows 10 docker toolbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably obvious question but are you launching the app on http://localhost:8080 ??

Try with following simplified nginx config

```
upstream backend {
    server backend_container_name:8080;
}

upstream frontend{
    server frontend_container_name:4200;
}


server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;

    server_name $hostname;
    include extensions/proxy.conf;

    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/api/;
    
    }

    

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With angular, you should not use npm start or ng serve in prod. You should first build the angular project with ng build and then serve the files outputed from the dist folder.